# How to extract PDF content and upload it to a table in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I just want to know if there are ways to read and extract the content of a PDF file then upload it to my table in APEX

Im using APEX 5.0 by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you meant to display pdf file as embedded in your app. you may check this sample
https://arrayofpointers.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/upload-and-view-a-file-imagepdfdoc-in-a-list-of-oracle-apex-page/

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but to qoute again my problem, I just want to know if there are ways to `read and extract the content` of a PDF file.I dont know if this is doable in apex.But i really need suggestions on how to do it. Thanks for answering again by the way.

Comment: are you able to give more details about your pdf files? like scanned images or a system generated pdfs and how do you want to do it in apex. will your end user upload it frequently or will you transfer your initial data to apex tables depending on your needs there might be different options. for example if you plan to do it online you may sent your files to an online pdf-to-text or ocr web service with rest and parse the  incoming text file to the table fields

Comment: or you may use ORACLE TEXT http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/afilsupt.htm#CCREF1300